# Preventing appearance of certain directories/pages in google search results

Tags: search-engines

I have my personal homepage, and I want the main page itself to appear in search results. But I do not want a certain directory and its subdirectories to appear in google search results. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several mechanisms you can use to do this.

The first is the [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file.  This is a protocol which is voluntarily followed by "good" search engines by google, and allows you to list sections of your site which they will not follow.

> User-agent: *
>   Disallow: /myfolder/

The next is meta tags.  Individual pages can be tagged with metadata which tells robots not to index or display them.  Google has a [nice writeup on how to implement these](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812).

> `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">`

The final mechanism, if the pages have already been indexed, is to use the search engine's removal mechanism if one exists. I've linked to the documentation for Google, Bing, and Yahoo's removal mechanisms here:

- [Google URL removal](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734)
- [Bing URL removal](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/blogs/webmaster/archive/2009/01/28/removing-content-from-the-live-search-index.aspx)
- [Yahoo URL removal](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/search/siteexplorer/siteexplorer-46.html)

Answer (score 0):

disallow the search bots to enter these locations:

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

google describes the procedure [pretty good](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449), example given:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder1/
```

This disallows all bots to index the content of "/folder1/"

Answer (score 0):

Use a robots.txt file in your main folder and set it to:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

In the folder you don't want anyone to access put a robots.txt file with this body:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Checkout http://www.robotstxt.org/ for more info about robot.txt files.

Comment: robots.txt files won't get picked up in subdirectories, only at the document root.